# What does Cairne Bloodhoof mean by "a pup still wet behind the ears"?

Tags: warcraft

This is a quote from War Crimes:

> “For the Thrall I knew, who befriended the tauren and helped them so greatly, would not have blithely handed over the Horde he restored to a young pup still wet behind the ears!”

Excerpt From: Golden, Christie. “World of Warcraft: War Crimes.”

I understand he means that Garrosh (the young pup) is not ready to be leader of the Horde.

But what does the "still wet behind the ears" part mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wet_behind_the_ears

Comment: yep pretty much google wet behind the ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [here](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-does-it-mean-to-be-wet-behind-the-ears.htm):

> To be wet behind the ears essentially means to be inexperienced,
>   unseasoned or even a bit naïve or immature. In the business world,
>   this phrase is often applied to new employees who are not quite ready
>   to accept the full responsibility of their positions yet. It is also
>   common for older people to express skepticism over a younger person's
>   skills or level of authority by claiming he or she is still "wet
>   behind the ears." At some point, however, a rookie or trainee usually
>   does gain the needed experience or wisdom.
>
> The origin of the phrase appears to be purely American, with some
>   sources tracing it back several hundred years. It is more likely that
>   the description came into popular use around the 19th century, as the
>   lingo of the cowboys became more common. One theory holds that "wet
>   behind the ears" started off as a description of newborn and young
>   calves, which began their lives covered in mucus and other fluids. As
>   these calves matured, the last part of their bodies to become
>   completely dry were patches located behind their ears. In that sense,
>   the phrase was cowboy shorthand for an inexperienced or green ranch
>   hand.
>
> It is also possible that the phrase "wet behind the ears" started with
>   human babies, who are also born covered in a layer of mucus and
>   tissue. Unlike a calf, however, a human baby is often dried by a nurse
>   or its mother shortly after birth. The analogy could be more
>   metaphorical in nature, however. Until a child reaches a certain level
>   of maturity or gains a certain amount of "street smarts," he or she
>   could still be considered a little wet behind the ears.
>
> This is not to say that being considered "wet behind the ears" is
>   necessarily a bad thing. Virtually every occupation or interest has a
>   breaking-in period, and eventually most people achieve a state of
>   competency and maturity as their skills improve. Almost everyone
>   experiences a feeling of being unsure of themselves when confronted
>   with a more advanced set of responsibilities or job requirements. Time
>   and experience are the only things that will help convert a young
>   intern or student into a competent and confident employee.

Honestly though this falls into the `let me google that for you` category pretty much.

Comment: Question seems a better fit for English Language & Usage, though "lert me duckduckgo it for you" still applies.